# Jena sparql (Dbpedia) query OPTIONAL filter gives no results but (http://dbpedia.org/snorql/) same query works

Tags: java, sparql, jena, dbpedia

hello ive this query in this site working http://dbpedia.org/snorql/

```
   PREFIX ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?author ?name ?wiki  ?desc ?thumb WHERE {
?author a ontology:Book;
rdfs:label ?name;
ontology:wikiPageID ?wiki;
ontology:abstract ?desc.
OPTIONAL {?author <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail> ?thumb }.
FILTER (lang(?name) = 'en')
FILTER (regex(?name,  "lo") || regex(?desc, "lo"))
FILTER (lang(?desc) = 'en').
}ORDER BY ?name LIMIT 100
```

but in my jena queryFactory java class it only works if i remove Optional filter for thumbnail at this line :

```
OPTIONAL {?author <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail> ?thumb }.
```

here is my jena java method that works :

```
private String authorQuery(String entity, String keyWord, String language) {

        return addPrefix("rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>") +
                addPrefix("rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>") +
                addPrefix("dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>") +
                addPrefix("ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>") +

                addQuery("SELECT DISTINCT ?author ?name ?wiki  ?desc ?thumb WHERE {\n" +
                        "?author a ontology:" + entity + ";\n" +
                        "rdfs:label ?name;\n" +
                        "ontology:wikiPageID ?wiki;\n" +
                        "ontology:abstract ?desc;\n" +
                        "<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail> ?thumb.\n" +
                        "FILTER (lang(?name) = '" + language + "') " +
                        "FILTER (regex(?name,  \"" + keyWord + "\") || regex(?desc,  \"" + keyWord + "\"))\n" +
                        " FILTER (lang(?desc) = '" + language + "')." +
                        "}\n" +
                        "ORDER BY ?name\n" +
                        "LIMIT 40000");
    }
```

but as soon as i add optionnal keyword in this line :

```
"<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail> ?thumb.\n" +
```

No result are returned, can someone tell me why? :(

PS : it work well without OPTIONAL FILTER

Edit : whole DbpediaQuery class

```
public class DbPediaQuery {
    //array of authors
    private DbPediaQuery() {
    }

    public static DbPediaQuery createDbPediaQuery() {
        return new DbPediaQuery();
    }

    public LinkedList<Entity> queryAuthor(String entity, String keyWord, String language) {
        LinkedList<Entity> temp = new LinkedList<>();
        Query query = QueryFactory.create(authorQuery(entity, keyWord, language));

        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);
        try {
            temp.addAll(collectAuthors(qexec.execSelect()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return temp;
    }

    private String authorQuery(String entity, String keyWord, String language) {

        return addPrefix("rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>") +
                addPrefix("rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>") +
                addPrefix("dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>") +
                addPrefix("ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>") +

                addQuery("SELECT DISTINCT ?author ?name ?wiki  ?desc ?thumb WHERE {\n" +
                        "?author a ontology:" + entity + ";\n" +
                        "rdfs:label ?name;\n" +
                        "ontology:wikiPageID ?wiki;\n" +
                        "ontology:abstract ?desc;\n" +
                        "<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail> ?thumb.\n" +
                        "FILTER (lang(?name) = '" + language + "') " +
                        "FILTER (regex(?name,  \"" + keyWord + "\") || regex(?desc,  \"" + keyWord + "\"))\n" +
                        " FILTER (lang(?desc) = '" + language + "')." +
                        "}\n" +
                        "ORDER BY ?name\n" +
                        "LIMIT 40000");
    }

    private LinkedList<Entity> collectAuthors(ResultSet results) {
        LinkedList<Entity> temp = new LinkedList<>();
        while (results.hasNext()) {
            Entity a = new Entity();
            QuerySolution row = results.next();
            String fullName = row.get("name").toString().substring(0, row.get("name").toString().indexOf("@"));
            String biography = row.get("desc").toString().substring(0, row.get("desc").toString().indexOf("@"));
            a.setTitle(fullName);
            a.setWikiID(Integer.parseInt(row.get("wiki").toString().substring(0, row.get("wiki").toString().indexOf("^"))));
            if (!row.get("thumb").toString().isEmpty())
                a.setPictureURL(row.get("thumb").toString());
            else
                a.setPictureURL("http://www.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.elated.com%2Fres%2FImage%2Farticles%2Fmanagement%2Fapache%2Fmaking-a-custom-error-page%2Fapache_404_default.gif&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fjdorn%2Fphp-reports%2Fissues%2F43&h=241&w=400&tbnid=KQI5AbkkVp3-uM%3A&zoom=1&docid=6Bd7CTaQ291_UM&ei=5AU0VceoI87WPYOvgCg&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=3255&page=1&start=0&ndsp=20&ved=0CDYQrQMwBw");
            a.setBiography(biography);
            temp.add(a);
            System.out.println("FAAT" + a.getTitle());
        }
        return temp;
    }

    private String addPrefix(String prefix) { return "PREFIX " + prefix + "\n"; }

    private String addQuery(String query) { return query; }
}
```

Comment: as an aside, the way that you're concatenating strings is very error prone.  What happens if language or keyWord ever contains a `"` character?  Also, you shouldn't compare language tags with `lang(...) = ...`, but with langMatches: `langMatches(lang(...),...)`.

Comment: thanks for the advice, ill change it, but my main problem at the moment is this optional, i want return also entities that not have thumbs :( like in snorql example...

Comment: Change your optional `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail>` with `ontology:thumbnail`. It might be resolved. Also, what kind of error does it generate?

Comment: @Artemis I agree that ontology:thumbnail would be better *style*, since the prefix is defined, but it's the same URI, so that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Do you zero results, or do you get some kind of error?

Comment: it doesn't generate any errors, but resultset is lesser cause it picks only resluts that have ontology:thumbnail ... Also  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/thumbnail> or ontology:thumbnail doesn't seem to change anything for me i changed that only to test and forget to put back ontology:thumbnail

Comment: @StackItEasy No, I mean when you **add** the optional, do you get no results, or do you get an **error** from Jena?

Comment: And without the source of you addPrefix, addQuery, etc, methods, we can't actually know what authorQuery is returning, so we don't know what your **actual** query is for certain.

Comment: One thought (hopefully it doesn't make a difference) what happens if you remove the `.` after the optional block?

Comment: i added the whole class, its a bit ugly ;) but it work well, giving me lot of result for lot of String entity like (Actor, cinema, place, Year ....)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor i tried with removing  the dot after optionnal block... no results... but without filter, more than 10k results for ontology:AnatomicalStructure with an empty keyword search...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figured it out after logging several things... First ive loged the resultset size, with the optional filter it gave me more results than if i put no optional filter... 2383 vs 2103(without optional).. then i noticied that if

`a.setPictureURL(row.get("thumb2").toString());` is empty or null the loop dont continue... it stoped after 14 results and gave me no return for this method :

```
private LinkedList<Entity> collectAuthors(ResultSet results) {
        LinkedList<Entity> temp = new LinkedList<>();
        while (results.hasNext()) {
            Entity a = new Entity();
            QuerySolution row = results.next();
            String fullName = row.get("name").toString().substring(0, row.get("name").toString().indexOf("@"));
            String biography = row.get("desc").toString().substring(0, row.get("desc").toString().indexOf("@"));
            a.setTitle(fullName);
            a.setWikiID(Integer.parseInt(row.get("wiki").toString().substring(0, row.get("wiki").toString().indexOf("^"))));
            if (!row.get("thumb").toString().isEmpty())
                a.setPictureURL(row.get("thumb").toString());

            a.setBiography(biography);
            temp.add(a);
            System.out.println("FAAT" + a.getTitle());
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

so i just checked with `if(row.getResource("thumb2")!=null)` like that

```
    if(row.getResource("thumb")!=null)
   a.setPictureURL(row.get("thumb").toString());
```

and then the loop continued ---> problem solved

Thanks everyone for your hints and be carefull of empty reslutset columns with Jena

Comment: You should accept your own answer for future reference.

Comment: i need to wait 2 days cause i dont get enough contribution... but you should also accept it :)

Comment: @StackItEasy You're the only one that can **accept** an answer to your question;  the rest of us can only upvote or downvote it.

Comment: `a.setPictureURL(row.get("thumb2").toString());` I don't see **thumb2** anywhere in the question;  just **thumb**.  Where did **thumb2** come into play?